# Python For Loop Syntax to Java

Tags: java, python, for-loop, syntax

```
 for j in [c for c in coinValueList if c <= cents]:
```

How would you write this for loop out in java?
Is it

```
for(j=0, j <= cents, j++){
    for(c=0; c<= cents, j++){
```

I'm not sure what c and j are supposed to be compared to.
CoinValueList = {1,5,10,25}
cents = 0 -- it's in its own for loop before these two.

Comment: You're iterating over data in a list in the python code above, so below it would be how you sequentially access a list or array's data.

Comment: I would think it definitely is not the java code as posted.  Why not explain in english what logic you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's decompose:

```
array = [c for c in coinValueList if c <= cents] # produces an array of coins from coinValueList that are <= cents
for j in array: # iterates over array
    #stuff
```

So we can do that in only one loop, and the java equivalent would be:

```
for(int j=0; j<coinValueList.length; j++) {
    if(coinValueList[j] <= cents) {
        #stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to translate very literally in Java

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList();

for(Integer c : coinValueList) {
    if(c <= cents) {
        newList.append(c);
    }   
}

for(Integer j : newList) {
    # do something
}
```

but normally you don't need second `for` loop